# Spaces between Menu items acting like invisible text

Tags: css, list, navigation, cursor, menubar

A few weeks ago I was asked by my church to create a new website for them which I happily obliged to. I've already created a mockup in PS and I'm coding it right now. I created the navigation bar and it is working properly as I had intended.

However I'm running into a glaring problem concerning the spaces in between the menu items. It seems like it may be an easy fix, but I cannot seem to figure it out. The menu bar is set up as unordered and ordered lists. I have them evenly spread out, but in between the empty spaces, the mouse cursor changes from a pointer into an "I" bar, as if there is invisible text.

For me, this is not ideal, and I'd much prefer that when hovering over this empty space between the menu items that it would stay as a pointer for the cursor instead of this "I" bar. Also, if you highlight the entire menue, the spaces also highlight as well and connect with the menu items. That is also not ideal for me, and it makes me confused why the empty spaces are sort of acting like invisible text.

Here is my menu bar CSS code:

```
<style type="text/css">

nav {
position: relative;
width:960px;
z-index:9999;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
padding:0;
background-color:transparent;
text-align:justify;
}

#bar1 {
background-color:transparent;
padding:0;
text-align: justify;
overflow: hidden;
height:39px;
border-top: 1px solid #222222; border-bottom: 1px solid #90908e;
background-color:transparent;
}

#bar1>li {
display:inline-block;
margin-top:8px;
height:100%;
background-color:transparent;


}

#bar1>li>a {
font-family:'Oswald',Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:15px;
color:#464748;
text-decoration:none;
}

#bar1>li>a:hover,#bar1>li>a:active,#bar1>li:hover>a {
font-family:'Oswald',Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
 font-size:15px;
color:#2b77a0;
text-decoration:none;   
}

#bar1>li>ul>li {
border-top: none;
height:33px;
margin-top:8px;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
text-decoration:none;
background-color:transparent;
padding-top:7px;
}

#bar1>li:hover>ul>li{
display:block;
}
#bar1>li>ul>li{
display:none;
text-decoration:none;
}

#bar1>li>ul>li>a
{
font-family:'Antenna Thin', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:15px;
color:#222222;
text-decoration:none;
}

#bar1>li>ul>li>a:hover, #bar1>li>ul>li>a:active, #bar1>li>ul>li:hover>a,
{
font-family:'Antenna Thin', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color:#222222;
}

li {
list-style-type:none;
}

.filler 
{
width:100%;
display: inline-block;
height:0px;
cursor:pointer;
}
</style>
```

And here is my HTML coding (Ignore the comments, I use them so I don't get lost when I take breaks):

```
<nav>
<ul id="bar1">

    <!--Begin About Us-->
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a>
        <!--Begin drop down menu items-->
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><font color="#2b77a0">•</font> New to Nederland First Assembly</a>          
                <a href="#"><span style="margin-left:10px;"><font color="#2b77a0">•</font> Our History</span></a>
                <a href="#"><span style="margin-left:10px;"><font color="#2b77a0">•</font> Our Beliefs</span></a>
            </li>

        </ul>
        <!--End drop down menu items-->
    </li>
    <!--End About Us-->

            <!--Begin Ministries-->
    <li><a href="#">MINISTRIES</a>
        <!--Begin drop down menu items-->
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><font color="#2b77a0">•</font> Kids</a>          
                <a href="#"><span style="margin-left:10px;"><font color="#2b77a0">•</font> Youth</span></a>
                <a href="#"><span style="margin-left:10px;"><font color="#2b77a0">•</font> Women</span></a>
                <a href="#"><span style="margin-left:10px;"><font color="#2b77a0">•</font> Men</span></a>
            </li>

        </ul>
        <!--End drop down menu items-->
    </li>
    <!--End Ministries-->

                    <!--Begin Events-->
    <li><a href="#">EVENTS</a>
        <!--Begin drop down menu items-->
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><font color="#2b77a0">•</font> Latest News</a>          
                <a href="#"><span style="margin-left:10px;"><font color="#2b77a0">•</font> Monthly Calendar</span></a>
            </li>

        </ul>
        <!--End drop down menu items-->
    </li>
    <!--End Events-->

                        <!--Begin Listen Online-->
    <li><a href="#">LISTEN ONLINE</a>
        <!--Begin drop down menu items-->
        <ul style="background-color:red;">
            <li>
                <a href="#"><font color="#2b77a0">•</font> Sermons</a>          
                <a href="#"><span style="margin-left:10px;"><font color="#2b77a0">•</font> Teachings</span></a>
                <a href="#"><span style="margin-left:10px;"><font color="#2b77a0">•</font> Archive</span></a>
            </li>

        </ul>
        <!--End drop down menu items-->
    </li>
    <!--End Listen Online-->
    <li><a href="pages/contact.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
    <li class="filler"></li>
</ul>
```

And here is hopefully a working JS Fiddle:
    http://jsfiddle.net/Broli/yemze0je/1/

Comment: Your lis need to be inlined in your code. If there's white space between them in your html it will show small white space when LIs are painted in the browser, even with `display:inline-block`.

Comment: You can add padding to the links to make them each wider, so they'd meet in the middle. (To make padding work for <a> elements you have to also set them to display: block or inline-block). This is another method that might help: http://css-tricks.com/equidistant-objects-with-css/

Comment: This normal behavior since you are justifying. The cursor changes to a pointer on a link, this is good, it turns off when it's not a link, and there's not a link between the items.

Comment: The cursor is for when it's a link, the problem is addressed in my answer. You need an arrow when it's not a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inline block assigns a font size based on the default, what you want is the hand icon on a link, and the arrow when it's not a link:

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/yemze0je/3/

```
nav {
    position: relative;
    width:960px;
    z-index:9999;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding:0;
    background-color:transparent;
    text-align:justify;
    font-size:0px; /* due to inline-block on children */
}
```

Because your font size is specified in the children, this does just that.

Comment: Ah! Bootstrap, that is exactly what I was looking for. I had no idea that the inline-element did that with font sizes. This was such a huge headache for me, and it had such a simple solution. Thank you very much for your feedback and resolving my issue. Your help, along with everyone else input is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First off, comments are good for you! :-)

My immediate thought looking at your HTML is that you should be wrapping each anchor within its own list item.

Change this and the markup will probably behave in the way that you would like it to.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp

Alternatively, if you would like to keep the same markup, you could mask the issue by setting the cursor with CSS, like this;

ul, li{cursor: default;}

I am presuming that the li or ul will need the curser set (I'm on my smartphone!)

Comment: I tried to wrap each <a> element within its own <li> tag, including both the main navigation items and the sub-menu items. However, I still have the same issue concerning the empty spaces between the main navigation items. I'm perfectly fine with the amount of empty space between the navigational words, but I believe the inline-block is causing that unnecessary "I" bar that appears every time I place my mouse over the empty spaces between the words in the navigation bar. The menu works perfectly fine, I'm just still struggling with this issue because it gives the illusion of hidden text.

Comment: I really hate masking issues and not resolving them fully, but I think your cursor idea will keep me very sane. :) I think I'll use this for the time being and continue to work on the rest of the coding. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The cursor is for when it's a link, the problem is addressed in my answer. You need an arrow when it's not a link.